# jQuery - load images before making height 100%

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a problem with making div height 100%. Code below works fine only if images are loaded in cache. Otherwise some content is hidden.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".stage > div > p > input").live("change", function() {
    var cat=jQuery(this).val();
    var self = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent();
    jQuery("#pleaseWait").css("display","block");
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo get_permalink(177); ?>",
            data: {
                    curPage: <?php echo $post->ID; ?>,
                    id: cat }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        jQuery(self).next().html(msg);
        jQuery("#pleaseWait").css("display","none");
        var     el=jQuery(self).next(),
                curHeight=el.height(),
                autoHeight=el.css('height', 'auto').height();
        el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to load images only after jquery return response i.e. `jQuery(self).next().html(msg);`,
and before getting height 100% value in pixels i.e. `autoHeight=el.html(msg).css('height', 'auto').height();`

Those images are in `div class="answer"`, so it could be `$('.answer img).each(function () { ... });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use load handler of images:

```
$('.answer img').on('load', function () {
    if (this.complete) $(this).data('loaded', true);
    if ($('.answer img').length === $('.answer img').filter(    
    function () {
        return $(this).data('loaded')
    }).length) {
        //all images loaded
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `load function` for this,

```
el.load(function(){
    $(this).height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: The problem is with `var autoHeight=el.css('height', 'auto').height();`, when I send `autoHeight` value to console and I get image which wasn't in my cache, I was getting wrong value. So i need to load images first, then get `autoHeight` value.